# Set margin in textbox

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, position, background-image

I am having a normal asp.net text box with a background image with properties as shown below:

```
.userbackground
{
    background-image: url('../images/user.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

This is the view of my textbox:

[image]

And here is my textbox:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
 BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD" MaxLength="0" 
 AutoCompleteType="Disabled" CssClass="userbackground"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now I would like to know is there any possiblity to set the margin for the inside text or place the cursor position after that image and if user clears the text inside the cursor should stop before the image.

I have tried using css properties: text align:middle but it starts from the center and I don't want that and making a background image also dosen't suits my needs.showing and hiding image also is not a good option in my case as I have many.Other than these three options anyone can opt me the best way I am really glad to hear them.

Comment: you should use padding-left it will work

Comment: no,I have tried event that too it didn't work.

Comment: Your `.userbackground` element is an `<input>`. If so… does it have 16px width?

Comment: yes,I have updated with my textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the textbox in a `div` with a `background-image`, and position the textbox with padding so that it doesn't overlap the image:

```
​.textbox
{
 background-image:url('http://placehold.it/15/15');   
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:3px 3px;
 border:solid 1px black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left:20px;
 width:200px;
}
.textbox input
{
 border:none;
 background:transparent;
 width:100%;     
 outline: none; //removes orange border in google chrome
}
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/frBdL/)

Comment: this is what did the trick for me `padding-right:40px; background-position:20px` (when using a textbox with rtl direction)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this whithout a surrounding `<div>` element. But keep in mind, that the input must be defined as a block element `display:block;` in order to apply padding.

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/frBdL/3/)**

```
<input type="text" />

input
{
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/15/15');   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:3px 3px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:200px;
    height:22px;
    display:block;
    padding-left:20px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: @simiko-This is also great!, + 1 for the demo.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `padding-left` in your style .plz check online demo http://jsfiddle.net/SJBbs/1/. if your problem not solved yet then please leave your comments..

Comment: padding-left is the solution here. Just add `CssClass` property of TextBox and set it to a css class containing for example `padding-left:5px;`

Comment: If padding-left doesn't work it has to be another css rule overriding the padding one.